# Why overflow-y:hidden of HTML-lists makes bullet/number to be invisible?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, hidden, bulletedlist

I set `<li>`'s CSS property `overflow-y` to `hidden`, then its bullet/number was removed. Why? What is their relation? (How can I correct it?)

Here is a simple sample (With regard to [@Paulie_D answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40910926/why-overflow-yhidden-of-html-lists-makes-bullet-number-to-be-invisible#answer-40912185), I added `overflow-x:visible`):

```css
li:first-child {
  overflow-y:hidden; 
  overflow-x:visible;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Unordered list - Item 1</li>
    <li>Unordered list - Item 2</li>
</ul>
<ol>
    <li>Ordered list - Item 1</li>
    <li>Ordered list - Item 2</li>
</ol>
```

I ran it on Firefox v49.x and Chrome v54.x.

---

**EDIT:**
Due to some answers, I explain:

[image]

Bullets/Numbers are outside of *x-bounds*, no *y-bounds*!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my reading, when you set `overflow-y:hidden` the `overflow-x` *computed* value is set to `auto` which is part of the [**CSS Spec**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-3/#propdef-overflow-y).

> Computed value: as specified, except with visible computing to auto if one of overflow-x or overflow-y is not visible.

...and `overflow:auto`

> This value indicates that the box’s content is clipped to the padding box.

..and since the marker is outside of the `li` it's clipped and so hidden.

Comment: Thanks for your useful information. With regard to your answer, I updated my question.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you add `overflow-x:visible` it will revert to `auto`

Comment: So I accepted your answer, but now my question is **how to correct it?**

Comment: I'm not sure you can. It's not really clear why you need to restrict overflow anyway.

Comment: This is a great answer providing the actual explanation on why it disappears: "the content is clipped to the padding box". Thumbs up!

Answer (score 7):

The bullets are *outside* of list elements by default so `overflow-y:hidden;` hides them. You can use `list-style-position: inside;` to override the default `outside` value.

> I know that; but they are outside of x-boundaries, no y-boundaries!

Check this image:

[image]

The blue box is the bounding box of the list element. The space before the list elements is the default padding of the parent `ul` and `ol` elements. So the bullets are *outside* of the list elements.

Comment: I know that; but they are _outside of x-boundaries_, no _y-boundaries_!

Comment: ... So the bullets are outside of the list elements. Yes, are outside. But outside of x-boundaries! I have set `overflow-y` to `hidden`. I explained it better in my question.

Answer (score 0):

cause the bullet in Unordered  list or numbers in Ordered list are something more than the bounding box

Comment: I know that; but they are _outside of x-boundaries_, no _y-boundaries_!